# Fine Tuning mT5 Model for QA

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, model, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I want to fine-tune a mT5-small model for QA task.

I loaded and preprocessed the data.

When I use Colab Notebook, I have to do the following:

```
!pip install transformers
!pip install sentencepiece

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/mt5-small", use_fast=False)
```

Then I receive the following:

```
You are using the legacy behaviour of the <class 'transformers.models.t5.tokenization_t5.T5Tokenizer'>. This means that tokens that come after special tokens will not be properly handled. We recommend you to read the related pull request available at https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/24565
```

Which I hope is ok. If I don't install `sentencepiece` and do not set `use_fast=False`, I get another error that tells me to do that.

Now I don't know how to use the tokenizer.

I have the `train_questions` array, `train_answers` array, and `train_contexts` array.